# While listening to music on head set: How to avoid sound playing from phone speakers when push event occurs?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, huawei-u8860

I use my Android phone to listen to music at work with standard headset. Yet once an event occurs, e.g. e-mail recieved, the phone switches to standard speakers and plays the music and event sound over it, and then returns back to headset.

I want all my sounds to only play over the headset. How do configure my Huawei Honor to do so?

Comment: I don't know how to force Android to play everything through the headset, as your question is directed to. But would it be an option for you to let notifications be "silent" while listening to music? In that case I might have an idea.

Comment: @Izzy That would be a valid workaround so please share  your idea.

Comment: OK, done. I can only speak for *Tasker*, as I don't use any other app -- but I'm pretty sure *Llama* can handle it similarly. Don't worry the price of *Tasker*: it's 100% worth it, but if you first wanna try, there's a free trial available on their home page.

Answer (score 3):

While not 100% the desired *solution* (I don't know if there's any way to force Android playing sounds to a specific output device), as a work-around it is possible to *silence* undesired sources.

#### Background

As you mioght have noticed, Android has multiple "channels" for different kind of sounds, where you can adjust volume independently -- such as alarms, notifications, ringer tone, etc. So this can be used in the way of turning down unwanted types to zero, while keeping the once you want turned up. Of course, doing so manually can be a hazzle (and one might forget to reverse changes afterwards, especially when in a hurry). So let's look for an...

#### Automation

There are several "automation apps" on the playstore which might handle this, such as [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Using the latter, I can for sure say it can handle this in the following way:

**Condition:** App running (select apps you want to match)
**Task:** (Volume adjust: chose which ones you want to change to zero here, but keep *media volume* on)

What will happen now? Once an app from your selection comes to foreground, the rule will match and the volumes will be adjusted accordingly. As soon as none of the apps you chose is running in foreground any longer, volume settings are reverted to what they have been before.